# Did not keep Nafil Roza after having intent to keep it

Tags: sawm

Peace be upon you,

Last night before I had slept I Made Intention to keep nafil Roza on the 1st day of Dhu Al-Hijjah. I said it to Allah that I intent to keep.

But I woke late for Fajar and then I did not keep my fast.

Is having intention to fast and then not keeping a sin and needs to be compensated in this case of nafil roza.

Comment: I am sorry but i dont understand what is nafil roza?

Comment: It means non obligatory fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a sin to leave and inshallah it is even a rewarded that you even intended to it, and that is by the Qudssi Hadith from Allah [SWT]

> Allah has written down the good deeds and the bad ones. Then He explained it [by saying that] he who has intended a good deed and has not done it, Allah writes it down with Himself as a full good deed, but if he has intended it and has done it, Allah writes it down with Himself as from ten good deeds to seven hundred times, or many times over. But if he has intended a bad deed and has not done it, Allah writes it down with Himself as a full good deed, but if he has intended it and has done it, Allah writes it down as one bad deed. It was related by al-Bukhari and Muslim.[Source](https://sunnah.com/qudsi40:16)

So inshallah it is rewarded that you even intended and tried, and then it could be that you got the whole reward which is from 10 to 700 Hasnat and that is that if you intended but then you forgot or something actually hindered you from fasting then it as you did it and that is supported by the Hadith from the prophet [pbuh]

> Actions are according to intentions, and everyone will get what was intended. Whoever migrates with an intention for Allah and His messenger, the migration will be for the sake of Allah and his Messenger. And whoever migrates for worldly gain or to marry a woman, then his migration will be for the sake of whatever he migrated for. [Source](https://40hadithnawawi.com/hadith/1-actions-are-by-intentions/)

So inshallah your fast is either counted as a whole fast or just the intent but inshallah it is not a sin for leaving it.

Hope that answers your question.
Allah knows best.

Comment: Jazak Allah Khairn